# What should the behavior of unique_ptr be in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Say I have the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> pA;
pA(new A);
```

In this convoluted example, what should the behavior of `pA(new A);` be?

As far as I can tell, in MSVC2010, `void operator()(T*) const;` from default_delete is called right after `new` returns and deletes the pointer right away. Whereas g++(4.7.0) gave me `no match for call (std::unique_ptr<A>)(A*)` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code should not compile.  `std::unique_ptr` does not overload `operator()`.

The Visual C++ 2011 Developer Preview rightly rejects the code.  Visual C++ 2010 only accepts the code due to [a bug in its `std::unique_ptr` implementation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633905/visual-c-ill-formed-unique-ptr-function-call-syntax).

Comment: Thanks, very fast answer and even gave me a link to the bug.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC employs the state-less deleter optimization for `unique_ptr`, i.e. it exploits the empty-base-class-optimization and just inherits from the deleter. Unfortunately, the inheritance is `public`, which is why you have access to the overloaded `operator()` of the `default_delete` functor.

Comment: I wonder why they would make the inheritance public in the first place?

Comment: @Jesse: A fluke maybe? Only STL knows. :P

Comment: Yeah, from what I heard, STL implements this stuff by himself, so I guess we would have to cut him some slack.